# Setting a Plugin Object

Tags: plugins, seo, plugin-seo

I'm currently using [SEO by EtherCreative](https://github.com/ethercreative/seo) on Craft 2, one of my pages needs a custom title and description injected into it like this on the docs:

> In some cases, you will not have access to an SEO field, but will want
>   to set the page title & description. You can do this by creating a
>   custom SEO object using the function below:

```
craft.seo.custom('The Page Title', 'The page description', $includeDefaultTitleSuffix)
```

Mine seems to be throwing errors or not doing anything like so:

```
  {% set seo = craft.seo.custom('Discount codes and vouchers for {{ query }}', 'You searched for {{ query }}. Check out the latest live {{ query }} discount codes & voucher codes for {{ "now"|date("m") }} {{ "now"|date("Y") }} only at Vouchertoday.uk') %}
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain the problem a little bit better? What doesn't work? What errors do you receive?

Answer (score 1):

You can't automatically expand variables inside strings in Twig as you would normally do in PHP.

Instead, you have to concatenate your strings.

```
{% set seo = craft.seo.custom('Discount codes and vouchers for ' ~ query, 'You searched for ' ~ query ~ '. Check out the latest live ' ~ query ~ ' discount codes & voucher codes for ' ~ now|date('m') ~ ' ' ~ now|date('Y') ~ ' only at Vouchertoday.uk') %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems to still not be setting the object?

Comment: Try {% do craft.seo.custom(all the stuffs) %} instead of setting it to a local variable. NB: I haven't used this exact plugin myself, so I'm just trying to apply logic to it :)

Comment: This throws an error.

Comment: "Unexpected token "operator" of value "=" ("end of statement block" expected)."

Comment: Hmm, could you post the entire line? There's no '=' in my example, so I need to see where else it could be going wrong